# Add indicator that account is scheduled to be deleted on the network profile

Tags: feature-request, deleted-accounts, network-profile

It'd be useful to have an indicator telling us which of our accounts are marked to be deleted on the "accounts" tab of our StackExchange profiles.

This could be used, for example, by a user who has requested the deletion of several accounts to make sure that the admins have approved the deletion of all of them, and that he has already clicked on every confirmation link.